# PLPGSQL catch any exception in loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function for geocoding, it works fine without the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` part. However, I want the loop continue in case if there is an exception. So I am trying to do this by using `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mygetcounty2() RETURNS void LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE idVariable uuid;
begin
FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP

SELECT id into idVariable FROM address_table WHERE county IS NULL AND parse_address_error = false LIMIT 1;

UPDATE address_table set county =
(select namelsad from tiger_data.county_all where ST_Contains( the_geom, ST_GeomFromText( (SELECT ST_AsText( ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout, 0.00001) ) As wktlonlat FROM geocode(address, 1 ) AS g), 4269 ) ))
where id = idVariable;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     UPDATE address_table set parse_address_error = true where id = idVariable;
END LOOP;
return;
end;
$$;
```

But I am getting the following message when trying to create the function

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"
LINE 15: EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 511
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I added a new `begin`, `end` block inside the loop. I no longer got an error when creating the function.

```
Create or replace function mygetcounty2()
returns void
language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE idVariable uuid;
begin
FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP

begin

SELECT id into idVariable FROM address_table WHERE county IS NULL AND parse_address_error = false LIMIT 1;

UPDATE address_table set county = 
(select namelsad from tiger_data.county_all where ST_Contains( the_geom, ST_GeomFromText( (SELECT ST_AsText( ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout, 0.00001) ) As wktlonlat FROM geocode(address, 1 ) AS g), 4269 ) ))
where id = idVariable;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise notice 'oops %', sqlstate;
     UPDATE address_table set parse_address_error = true where  id = idVariable;

    end;
END LOOP;
return;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have an `EXCEPTION` clause in a `LOOP` - `END LOOP` block.

Wrap the first `UPDATE` in its own `BEGIN` - `END` block and add the clause there.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you meant, but I did look at another answer you had made with a exception block inside a loop. I added a new BEGIN and END block inside the loop. It did create the function, and seems to be working now. I have not tested it extensively yet. From the code I have in case of an error the `update` will occur and the loop will continue?

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly than. If the error is hit, execution will continue after the `END`, so it will continue to loop. You should indent your code properly, otherwise it is unmaintenable.